# Where can I stay with a pool in room in north east USA?

Tags: usa, hotels, accommodation, resorts

My husband and I are looking for a hotel/resort/inn (etc.) that has the option of a room with a private pool. A fireplace and 2 person jacuzzi / hot tub would also be a big plus.

The accommodation must be in the mid-Atlantic / lower New England region of the USA (ie RI, MA, CT, NY, NJ, PA).

Comment: An exercise/lap pool (with or without one of those motors that you swim against) or bigger? Can it be indoors or outdoors?

Comment: @mkennedy: Doesn't have to be a "real" pool, just something that is bigger than a 2 person bathtub so that it can be swum in a bit. More for romance than exercise. Must be indoors.

Comment: swum, yeah.. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cove Pocono Resorts](http://covepoconoresorts.com/suites/covehavensuites.aspx) do offer what you're looking for.

---

It's also possible to bathe in a large champagne glass:

[image]

Comment: Did you stay there? What about privacy issues like cameras etc? What I want to ask is that they don't look at you from hidden cameras? BTW, some of their rooms don't have windows.

Comment: I live next to it.  I am not sure I understand the paranoia about hidden cameras.  I would say before installing hidden cameras they would think about their reputation which costs more.

Comment: Thanks. I think hidden cameras are more common in movies than in real life. Your point does make a lot of sense.

Comment: They have those spy shops now that sell hidden cameras.  You have to watch out.  You can't trust there are no hidden cameras just because some people on the internet said there are no hidden cameras.

Comment: @Karlson - I'm sorry dude, I simply had to add that image there  :O

Comment: If (or perhaps when?) someone asks on travel.stackexchange *"Where can I bathe in a large champagne glass?"* would it be appropriate to link back to here?

Comment: @JoeBlow :)  That's fine.  When I posted the answer I thought I'd avoid that and talking about the [Frequent Lovers Club](http://www.covepoconoresorts.com/forever-lovers-club)

Comment: @JoeBlow this would be an issue in any hotel room, I don't get where this sudden paranoia comes from.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 "Marvin Boggs: Do you know what's wrong with this country?
Sarah Ross: They all are trying to kill us?
Marvin Boggs: Exactly!"

Comment: @JoeBlow That was an interesting picture but IMO it's slightly NSFW so I removed it. You guys can add it again if you want, I'm not gonna get into an edit war or anything. But just my 2c.

Comment: @Fiksdal This actually was an advertising for awhile sitting right on top of Lincoln Tunnel.

Comment: @Karlson Alright, fair enough. I've been away from the West for too long.

Answer (score 2):

[Cape Cod](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cape_Cod) is the best lower NE loaction for travel as the area warms up. This hotel has [jacuzzi](http://www.sandwichlodge.com/cape-cod-lodging-jacuzzi-suite.asp) and a wonderful location -- my parents used to stay there.